# Spring Boot JDBC Connection to Google Cloud SQL not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, google-cloud-sql, spring-jdbc

I want to start by saying that when I run this locally, it works perfectly. When I deploy (./mvnw -DskipTests=true appengine:deploy) I deploys just fine with no errors and even appears to run on google cloud just fine. But when I try to use the registration form, i get the following error on submission.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 07 22:48:57 UTC 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

MY POM FILE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myApp</groupId>
<artifactId>myApp-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>trading-server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <mysql-connector.version>6.0.5</mysql-connector.version>
    <mysql-socket-factory.version>1.0.5</mysql-socket-factory.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Database Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Socket Factory for Cloud SQL -->
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Caching Dependencies -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.cache</groupId> <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId> <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->

    <!-- Webjars Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1-1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- START plugin -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- END plugin -->
</build>
```

APPLICATION PROPERTIES

```
    ## DATABASE
    database=mysql
    #spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:db/${database}/schema.sql
    spring.datasource.data=classpath*:db/${database}/data.sql

    # Web
    spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML

    # Hibernate
    hibernate.dialect.storage_engine = innodb

    # JPA
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

    # Spring Actuator Settings
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,beans,env,metrics,mapping,trace,sessions
    management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator


    # Active Spring profiles
    spring.profiles.active=mysql
```

APPLICATION-MYSQL.PROPERTIES

```
database=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/database?cloudSqlInstance=spring-test:us-central1:spring-main=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://###.#.#.#/database?cloudSqlInstance=spring-test:us-central1:spring-main=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=secret

spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

So again this works perfectly when I comment when i switch datasource.url above and run it locally. But I get the following error when I try to register an account on google cloud sql:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 07 22:48:57 UTC 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Comment: I would use another DB client to test if you could connect to google DB first

Comment: Check whether your App Engine Default Service Account has a role that allows it to access CloudSQL - if not, grant it as described in these [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#granting-access) (even if both App Engine and Cloud SQL are in the same project)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to connect is using spring cloud gcp.

I did [this repo](https://github.com/jordanks/springboot-gcp-sql) to provide a successful connection example.